# How to get tkinter textbox text after it has been changed?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is this the proper time to use a global variable? Should I be using `stringVar`? What can I do to collect the text after the user has changed it's value?

When I add a `print(my_msg)` statement below the `my_msg = sms_textbox.get('1.0', 'end-1c')` line in the `get_txtmsg()` function it will print that the text has changed.

The same `print(my_msg)` statement within the `askfilename_sms()` function returns `"Hi, how are you?"`

```
    def askfilename_sms():
        print(my_msg)

    ent3 = ttk.Labelframe(
        tab1, text='New Client Survey SMS')
    ent3.grid(
        row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW, padx=2, pady=2)

    ttk.Label(
        ent3, text='This....\n').grid(row=0, column=-0)

    def get_txtmsg():
        global my_msg
        my_msg = sms_textbox.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
        askfilename_sms()

    my_msg = "Hi, how are you?"

    sms_btn = ttk.Button(
        ent3, text="Send SMS Surveys",
        command=lambda: get_txtmsg())
    sms_btn.grid(
        row=1, column=1, padx=90, pady=10)
    sms_textbox = tk.Text(
        ent3, height=6, width=34)
    sms_textbox.insert(
        '1.0', my_msg)
    sms_textbox.grid(
        row=0, column=1)
```

EDIT:

So I am not really sure why this works but I put all the functions into one function and now it works(not thrilled but maybe it is the proper way):

```
    def get_txtmsg():
        global my_msg
        my_msg = sms_textbox.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
        sms_msg_box = tk.messagebox.askyesno(
            title='Are you ready to begin?',
            message='click to send')
        if sms_msg_box:
            tk.messagebox.showinfo(
                message='Please select New Client Report')
            sms_nc_filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
                title="Select New Client file",
                filetypes=(("excel files", "*.xls"), ("all files", "*.*")))
            if not sms_nc_filename:
                return
            else:
                send_sms.send_survey_text(sms_nc_filename, my_msg)

    my_msg = "Hi, how are you"

    sms_btn = ttk.Button(
        ent3, text="Send SMS Surveys",
        command=lambda: get_txtmsg())
    sms_btn.grid(
        row=1, column=1, padx=90, pady=10)
    sms_textbox = tk.Text(
        ent3, height=6, width=34)
    sms_textbox.insert(
        '1.0', my_msg)
    sms_textbox.grid(
        row=0, column=1)
```

Comment: You can get the text at any time with the `get` method. It looks like you're already doing that. Why do you think this isn't working? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Updated the code to be as complete as I can. Should I also create a list so that the data-frame isn't needing to be loaded?

It is really difficult to make this code "work" since it has to communicate with an API. Maybe I should cut it down more as a sort of test.

Comment: So when I add a `print(my_msg)` statement inside the `askfilename_sms()` it prints the original message.

Comment: When I add a `print(my_msg)` statement after `my_msg = sms_textbox.get('1.0', 'end-1c')` in the `get_txtmsg()` function, it does change. So it is somehow changing back in between the 2 steps.